# C# atualizar XML com base em outro XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmldocument, xslt

Hoje tenho a seguinte estrutura XML:

```
<ROOT>
    <TES IDTES="4780" IDPES="17522" />
    <TES IDTES="6934" IDPES="12343" />
    <TES IDTES="4781" IDPES="17523" />
    <TES IDTES="6935" IDPES="12344" />
</ROOT>
```

Para atualizar este XML tenho o seguinte:

```
<ROOT>
    <TES DEL="S" IDTES="4780" IDPES="17522" />
    <TES DEL="S" IDTES="6934" IDPES="12343" />
    <TES IDTES="7777" IDPES="17523" />
    <TES IDTES="2020" IDPES="12344" />
</ROOT>
```

Significa que tenho que excluir 2 tags TES com seus IDTES respectivos e adicionar mais 2 tags TES. Resultando em:

```
<ROOT>
    <TES IDTES="4781" IDPES="17523" />
    <TES IDTES="6935" IDPES="12344" />
    <TES IDTES="7777" IDPES="17523" />
    <TES IDTES="2020" IDPES="12344" />
</ROOT>
```

Pesquisei um pouco sobre Diff e Merge entre XMLs no C# mas não me ajudaram muito.

Como fazer isso com LINQ sem utilizar loopings?

Comment: Pode ser em LINQ usando alguns loopings?

Comment: Olá novamente Cigano :)
Eu simplifiquei o XML para facilitar o entendimento. Mas imagine uns 17MB de arquivo de base que eu devo atualizar com mais uns 3MB (linhas a excluir e a adicionar). Loopings poderiam ficar lento. Será que não tem uma forma de passar algo do tipo XMLdeBase.Delete.Select[IDTES in [array de ids]]? Forcei?

Comment: Não vejo outra maneira senão carregando estes arquivos em memória e ir manipulando.

Comment: Uma formatação diferente do arquivo ajudaria?

Comment: Eu inclui uma resposta usando o XSLT (`XslTransform` ou `XslCompiledTransform`) como alternativa ao LINQ. Acredito que possa ser mais eficiente (pode consumir mais memória, mas deve ficar mais rápido).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando LINQ com `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(@"
<ROOT>
    <TES IDTES=""4780"" IDPES=""17522"" />
    <TES IDTES=""6934"" IDPES=""12343"" />
    <TES IDTES=""4781"" IDPES=""17523"" />
    <TES IDTES=""6935"" IDPES=""12344"" />
</ROOT>");

XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(@"
<ROOT>
    <TES DEL=""S"" IDTES=""4780"" IDPES=""17522"" />
    <TES DEL=""S"" IDTES=""6934"" IDPES=""12343"" />
    <TES IDTES=""7777"" IDPES=""17523"" />
    <TES IDTES=""2020"" IDPES=""12344"" />
</ROOT>");
```

Nesse exemplo estou usando strings literais para criar os objetos, naturalmente você deve abrir os arquivos XML usando `Load()`:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
```

A ideia seria unir os 2 arquivos enquanto converte para uma lista de objetos mais simples:

```
var list = doc1.Element("ROOT").Elements().Select(m => new { 
        IDTES = (string)m.Attribute("IDTES"), 
        IDPES = (string)m.Attribute("IDPES"), 
        DEL = (string)m.Attribute("DEL") ?? "N" } // coalesce para "N" em caso de null 
    ).Union(doc2.Element("ROOT").Elements().Select(m => new { 
        IDTES = (string)m.Attribute("IDTES"), 
        IDPES = (string)m.Attribute("IDPES"), 
        DEL = (string)m.Attribute("DEL") ?? "N" }
    )
);
```

Filtrar essa lista com `Where` para obter as linhas a excluir e aplicar `Except` para produzir o resultado desejado:

```
var toDel = list.Where(m => m.DEL == "S").Select(m => new { m.IDTES, m.IDPES });
var result = list.Select(m => new { m.IDTES, m.IDPES }).Except(toDel);
```

Então é só gerar um novo `XDocument` a partir do resultado:

```
var doc3 = new XDocument(new XElement("ROOT",
           from r in result
           select new XElement("TES",
               new XAttribute("IDTES", r.IDTES),
               new XAttribute("IDPES", r.IDPES)
           )
      )
);
```

E gravar em disco com `Save()`:

```
doc3.Save("file.xml");
```

Comment: Como seria este exemplo se eu quiser carregar o XML a partir de um arquivo e não string?
Vlw.

Comment: `XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load("file.xml");`

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa a usar LINQ é usar transformação XSLT, que realiza transformações em nós XML usando templates compilados. Transformações XSLT usam DOM e carregam o XML na memória, mas os nós são selecionados com XPath, que tende a ser mais eficiente.

A desvantagem é que XSLT é uma outra linguagem (e não é tão trivial quanto parece à primeira vista). Vou descrever como seria uma solução para seu problema com XSLT (que você pode rodar com C#). Se a estrutura do seus documentos originais for similar à que você apresentou como exemplo, talvez você nem precise alterar o código e possa usá-lo sem alterações.

**Um breve resumo do funcionamento do XSLT**

O *transformador XSLT* recebe um *documento-fonte* (XML bem-formado) e um *documento XSL* (XML em linguagem XSLT) e produz um resultado em texto (pode ser XML, texto, fragmento XML, etc.) O documento XSL pode também ler fontes (arquivos) adicionais que são carregados através de uma função usada em expressões XPath (`document('caminho-do-arquivo')`). No seu caso, o arquivo que contém as substituições seria carregado desta forma. O transformador também aceita que dados sejam passados como parâmetro na hora da execução. Esses dados são passados para um elemento `<xsl:param>`no documento XSL. Você pode executar o transformador de várias formas. Existem serviços online, ferramentas de linha de comando (como Saxon, Xalan) e também APIs em C#, Java, PHP, Ruby, etc.

**Solução do seu problema usando C# e XSLT**

Vou chamar o arquivo original de `fonte.xml`:

```
<ROOT>
    <TES IDTES="4780" IDPES="17522" />
    <TES IDTES="6934" IDPES="12343" />
    <TES IDTES="4781" IDPES="17523" />
    <TES IDTES="6935" IDPES="12344" />
</ROOT>
```

E o arquivo com as substituições de `atualizacao.xml`:

```
<ROOT>
    <TES DEL="S" IDTES="4780" IDPES="17522" />
    <TES DEL="S" IDTES="6934" IDPES="12343" />
    <TES IDTES="7777" IDPES="17523" />
    <TES IDTES="2020" IDPES="12344" />
</ROOT>
```

O documento XSLT que chamarei de `atualiza.xsl` faz a transformação que você precisa. Se você executar um transformador XSL e passar `fonte.xml`como entrada, `atualizacao.xml` como o parâmetro que chamei de `arquivo`, e `atualiza.xsl` como o arquivo XSL, ele vai gerar este resultado:

```
<ROOT>
   <TES IDTES="4781" IDPES="17523"/>
   <TES IDTES="6935" IDPES="12344"/>
   <TES IDTES="7777" IDPES="17523"/>
   <TES IDTES="2020" IDPES="12344"/>
</ROOT>
```

O código C# para rodar o transformador XSLT é similar ao código abaixo (eu não testei - e não sou programador C# - portanto pode haver alguma imprecisão):

```
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

        XsltArgumentList par = new XsltArgumentList();
        par.AddParam("arquivo", "", "atualizacao.xml");

        XsltSettings s = new XsltSettings();
        s.EnableDocumentFunction = true;

        transform.Load("atualiza.xslt",s, new XmlUrlResolver());

        using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("resultado.xml")) 
        {
            transform.Transform("fonte.xml", par, stream);
        }
```

O documento XSLT está listado abaixo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="arquivo">atualizacao.xml</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="document($arquivo)" />

    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TES[not($doc/ROOT/TES/@IDTES=@IDTES and $doc/ROOT/TES/@IDPES=@IDPES and $doc/ROOT/TES/@DEL='S')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc/ROOT/TES[not(@DEL = 'S')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TES">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

O primeiro elemento dentro de `<xsl:stylesheet>` é

```
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

que gera um resultado endentado. Você pode removê-lo se desejar. O elemento seguinte:

```
    <xsl:param name="arquivo">atualizacao.xml</xsl:param>
```

recebe o parâmetro `arquivo` que você passa via C#. Se você não passar o parâmetro por algum motivo ele usará como valor default o nome `atualizacao.xml`.

O elemento seguinte

```
<xsl:variable name="doc" select="document($arquivo)" />
```

carrega o documento e, se encontrá-lo atribui a uma constante `doc` (que você pode usar através do documento como `$doc`).

O documento contém dois templates `<xsl:template>` onde ocorrem as transformacoes. O segundo template:

```
<xsl:template match="TES">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

simplesmente copia o nó inteiro com atributos e conteúdo. Ele só é chamado quando um elemento `<TES>` estiver sendo processado (ele não faz nenhuma restrição a onde esse nó está localizado, no arquivo-fonte ou no outro).

O primeiro template combina com o nó `ROOT`. Será o `<ROOT>`de `fonte.xml` e será chamado automaticamente. O elemento `<copy>` copia esse nó (vai produzir `<ROOT>...</ROOT>`). Dentro do nó há duas chamadas `xsl:apply-templates` que contém expressões XPath. Eles irão escolher o que será colocado dentro de `<ROOT>`.

O primeiro XPath:

```
TES[not($doc/ROOT/TES/@IDTES=@IDTES and $doc/ROOT/TES/@IDPES=@IDPES and $doc/ROOT/TES/@DEL='S')]
```

é *relativo* a `<ROOT>` (refere-se ao documento `fonte.xml`) e seleciona todos os elementos `<TES>` **exceto** os que têm `@IDTES` e `@IDPES` *iguais* aos atributos correspondentes de um `TES` do documento `atualizacao.xml` (`$doc/ROOT/TES`) que também tenha atributo `DEL='S'` (`$doc/ROOT/TES/@DEL='S'`). Desta forma ele passa por todos os elementos e não copia para a árvore-fonte os que devem ser removidos.

O segundo XPath

```
$doc/ROOT/TES[not(@DEL = 'S')]
```

atua apenas no documento `atualizacao.xml` (`$doc`), copiando para a árvore resultado apenas os nós que *não têm* atributo `DEL='S'`.

Informações sobre as classes de transformação XSLT do C#:

- [XSLT Argument List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx) - para passar parametros.
- [XSLTCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) - para transformar.

**Mais informações sobre XSLT**

- A [Especificação XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) contém tudo, mas a versão 2.0 ainda é pouco suportada.
- Eu escrevi um [Tutorial XSLT 1.0 em português](http://www.argonavis.com.br/cursos/xml/x100/x100_9_XSLT.pdf) em 1998 e atualizei em 2007. Já está desatualizado de novo, mas é útil se você tiver interesse em entender melhor o XSLT.
- Existe também um ambiente tipo *fiddle* para XSLT: http://www.xmlplayground.com/ onde você pode testar seu código (tem algumas limitações).

Comment: XSLT é uma ótima alternativa. Além de ser facilmente testável nos browsers modernos.

Comment: Its ALIVE!!!
Para o exemplo dado esta foi a solução. Ainda vou testar com alguns arquivos grandes que tenho. Vlw.

Comment: Considerei a resposta do Iuri mais correta por conta de performance. Mais detalhes na minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de alguns testes, obtive os seguintes resultados:

### Para um XML base de 53MB e um XML de atualização de 45KB

- Utilizando a solução com XslCompiledTransform leva o tempo de 5 min. para gerar o novo arquivo
- Utilizando a solução com XDocument leva o tempo de 13 segundos para gerar o novo arquivo

### Para um XML base de 45KB e um XML de atualização de 53MB

- Utilizando a solução com XslCompiledTransform leva o tempo de 16 min. para gerar o novo arquivo
- Utilizando a solução com XDocument leva o tempo de 13 segundos para gerar o novo arquivo

### Para ambos os XMLs com 53MB

- Utilizando a solução com XslCompiledTransform levou o tempo de mais de 1 hora e cancelei
- Utilizando a solução com XDocument leva o tempo de 20 segundos para gerar o novo arquivo

Desta forma alterei a resposta correta como sendo a do Iuri, já que no meu caso o projeto se demonstrou viável graças a esta solução.

Comment: Interessante esse benchmark. Você também mediu consumo de memória?

Comment: Seria interessante um comparativo desses em forma de artigo. Incluindo dados do ambiente (plataforma, memoria, etc.) Você poderia publicar em blog, portal, no InfoQ.

Comment: Com ambos os XMLs com 53MB no uso de memória e CPU foram parecidos. Quando o tempo de processamento é menor (~10 seg.), o XslCompiledTransform utiliza quase 2x MENOS que o XDocument. No meu caso o mais importante é o tempo e não uso de recurso. Dá até pra fazer uma lógica que dependendo do tamanho do XML e hora em que está sendo executado o processo você pode optar por Velocidade ou Uso de recurso.